# I am receiving an error when running a t-test + tidy() on the output

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I'm trying to run a t-test on the data below, but it's returning an error that says:

> `Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct. Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

food_consumption <- readr::read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-02-18/food_consumption.csv')

food_consumption %>% 
  mutate(vegan = if_else(food_category %in% c("Wheat and Wheat Products", "Rice", "Soybeans", "Nuts inc. Peanut Butter"), "Non-Animal Product", "Animal Product")) %>% 
  select(consumption, co2_emmission, vegan) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!vegan, names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(type = as.factor(type),
         vegan = as.factor(vegan)) %>%
  group_by(type) %>% 
  do(test = t.test(value~vegan, data = (.))) %>% 
  tidy(test)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? And how I can tidy the t-test output without error? If I exclude the `tidy(test)` bit at the end the t-test returns two list objects as expected, but if I try and call `tidy()` it returns the error above.

I'm following a tutorial that runs this exact same code (except it uses `gather` instead of `pivot_wider` but both produce the same dataset).  [Timestamped link here](https://youtu.be/VKCPYet9qLM?t=2472).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this. I've only changed the last two lines of your code.

```
food_consumption %>% 
  mutate(vegan = if_else(food_category %in% c("Wheat and Wheat Products", "Rice", "Soybeans", "Nuts inc. Peanut Butter"), "Non-Animal Product", "Animal Product")) %>% 
  select(consumption, co2_emmission, vegan) %>% 
  pivot_longer(!vegan, names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(type = as.factor(type),
         vegan = as.factor(vegan)) %>%
  
  # here what I've changed!
  nest_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(tidy(t.test(value~vegan, data = data)), .groups = "drop")

#> # A tibble: 2 x 11
#>   type    estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method   alternative
#>   <fct>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      
#> 1 co2_em~    93.7      108.       14.7     15.3  1.25e-47      984.    81.7     106.   Welch T~ two.sided  
#> 2 consum~     2.56      29.0      26.5      1.01 3.12e- 1     1334.    -2.40      7.53 Welch T~ two.sided
```

As you see with `nest_by` I *nest* the dataframe in two rows (one for each `type`). You then have a nested dataframe with two columns. The second column is a list of dataframes called `data`.

With `dplyr` version > 1.0, `summarise` is now more flexible and you can use it directly to make operations that return more than a value for each row. Check out `?dplyr` for more infos.

Therefore, you can directly apply `tidy` on your result as I did.

`.groups = "drop"` is just to remove an annoying message from `summarise`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `group_test` - creating groups by the `type` variable
2. `map(data, ~t.test(value~vegan, date = .x) %>% tidy` - we calculate `t.test`for each group
3. `unnest(test)` - expand the results into columns

````
      mutate(vegan = if_else(food_category %in% c("Wheat and Wheat Products", "Rice", "Soybeans", "Nuts inc. Peanut Butter"), "Non-Animal Product", "Animal Product")) %>% 
      select(consumption, co2_emmission, vegan) %>% 
      pivot_longer(!vegan, names_to = "type", values_to = "value") %>%
      mutate(type = as.factor(type),
             vegan = as.factor(vegan)) %>%
      group_nest(type) %>% 
      transmute(type, test = map(data, ~t.test(value~vegan, data = .x) %>% tidy)) %>% 
      unnest(test)```
    
        # A tibble: 2 x 11
          type      estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high
          <fct>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
        1 co2_emmi~    93.7      108.       14.7     15.3  1.25e-47      984.    81.7     106.  
        2 consumpt~     2.56      29.0      26.5      1.01 3.12e- 1     1334.    -2.40      7.53
        # ... with 2 more variables: method <chr>, alternative <chr>
````

Comment: Though undoubtedly correct, I feel this answer would benefit from both an explanation of *what* is being done and *why* it produces the desired result.

Comment: added explanations. Maybe my English is bad for a good explanation

Comment: This is really useful. I've accepted the other answer, as it's simpler for me to understand. But this is really useful nonetheless. Thank you!

Comment: @YuriySaraykin: Your English is fine.  And thank you.  `transmute()` was new to me.  It might be worth adding a bullet for that?  Still, a +1 from me now.